# Vue js 2- Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have a component:

```
<player-info :data="player"></player-info>
```

I would like to use the [vue-mask-input plugin](https://niksmr.github.io/vue-masked-input/) as a child component:

```
<masked-input v-model="date" mask="11 / 11 / 1111" placeholder="Date">
```

This is the whole component:

```
<template>
  <div id="info" class="player-info-card-content section-card">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h5 class="section-title"><i class="ion-ios-list-outline title-icon"></i> Overview</h5>
        <button @click="edit = !edit" class="button edit-button-wrapper">
          <i v-if="!edit" class="ion-edit edit-button"></i>
          <i v-if="edit" class="ion-close edit-button"></i>
        </button>
        <hr class="info-title-hr">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row info-content">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 info-box">
                <span class="info-label">Born</span>
                <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.birthday }}</p>
                <!--
                <input v-if="edit" type="text" v-mask="'999.999.999-99'">
                <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="birthday" v-model="player.birthday" value="{{ player.birthday }}">
                -->
                <div><masked-input v-model="date" mask="11 / 11 / 1111" placeholder="Date"></div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 info-box">
                <span class="info-label">Club</span>
                <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.club }}</p>
                <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="club" v-model="player.club" value="{{ player.club }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 info-box">
                <span class="info-label">Position</span>
                <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.position }}</p>
                <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="position" v-model="player.position" value="{{ player.position }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12 info-box">
                  <span class="info-label">Height</span>
                  <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.height }} <span v-if="player.height != ''"></span></p>
                  <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="height" v-model="player.height" value="{{ player.height }}">
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 info-box">
                <span class="info-label">Weight</span>
                <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.weight }} <span v-if="player.weight != ''">kg</span></p>
                <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="weight" v-model="player.weight" value="{{ player.weight }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 info-box">
                <span class="info-label">Foot</span>
                <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.foot }}</p>
                <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="foot" v-model="player.foot" value="{{ player.foot }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-12 info-box">
                <span class="info-label">Agent</span>
                <p v-if="!edit">{{ player.agent }}</p>
                <input class="info-data-input" v-if="edit" name="agent" v-model="player.agent" value="{{ player.agent }}">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row sub-section">
      <div class="col-12">
        <h5 class="title-margin section-title">
          <i class="ion-ios-stopwatch-outline title-icon"></i>
          Athletic performance
        </h5>
        <hr class="info-title-hr">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row info-content">
      <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 info-box">
            <span class="info-label">40m time</span>
            <p class="lg-strong-font">4.3<span>s</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 info-box">
            <span class="info-label">100m time</span>
            <p class="lg-strong-font">11.1<span>s</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6 col-md-3 player-info-data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-12 info-box">
            <span class="info-label">Vertical jump</span>
            <p class="lg-strong-font">65<span>cm</span></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import MaskedInput from 'vue-masked-input';
  export default {
      props: ['data'],
      data () {
          return {
            player: this.data.data,
            edit: false,
            date: '',
          }
      },
      computed: {
          link() {
            return `/player/info/edit/${this.player.id}`;
          }
      },
      components: {
        MaskedInput
      }
  }
</script>
```

Before updating to Vue v.2.4.4 I kept getting warning that it is a fragment instance:

> [Vue warn]: Attributes "v-model", "mask", "placeholder" are ignored on
>   component  because the component is a fragment instance:

After updating the Vue to v.2.4.4 that warning was gone, but I got a new error:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
 defined.

 found in

 ---> <MaskedInput>
        <PlayerInfo>
          <Player>
            <Root>
```

And this is the parent component on my page:

```
<div><player :player="{{ $player }}" :videos="{{ $videos }}"></player></div>
```

This parent component consists of this child components:

```
<template>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div>
        <player-card :data="player"></player-card>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <div>
        <player-info :data="player"></player-info>
      </div>
      <div>
        <player-videos :data="videos"></player-videos>
      </div>
      <div>
        <player-stats :player="player.data.seasons"></player-stats>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I am importing the Vue like so:

```
import Vue from 'vue/dist/vue';
window.Vue = Vue;
```

And this is how I create Vue instance:

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: 'body',
    data: window.videoApp
});
```

What am I doing wrong, how can I fix this?

Comment: Could it be because you're not closing the `<masked-input>` component tag?

Comment: I have tried with closing it as well, but the same error appeared.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. What version of `vue-masked-input` are you using?

Comment: ```"_from": "vue-masked-input@latest",
  "_id": "vue-masked-input@0.5.2",
  "_inCache": true,
  "_location": "/vue-masked-input",
  "_nodeVersion": "6.9.2",```

Comment: Do you have a fiddle so we can experiment with a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You can not select body tag as the main element you need to create a div for your vue instance. You need to create vue instance like this;

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    // Some data...
  },
  methods: {
    // Your methods...
  }
})
```

And your html file should look like this;

```
...
<body>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- Vue instance selects and creates components in this div -->
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: I still get the input mask as a fragment

Comment: `<div><masked-input v-model="date" mask="11 / 11 / 1111" placeholder="Date"></div>`
in this part of your template, you are'nt sending prop 'mask' properly i guess. This line you need to add column before 'mask' to send it as a vue property to the child component `:mask=...`

Comment: That is how it is described in the docs of the plugin on how to use it: https://niksmr.github.io/vue-masked-input/  Besides, I am not getting a property error, I am getting fragment instance error.

Answer (score 1):

Ref: [vue-masked-input](https://niksmr.github.io/vue-masked-input/), shows closing with />

```
<div><masked-input v-model="date" mask="11 / 11 / 1111" placeholder="Date" /></div>
```

but you don't have the self-close slash, or a closing tag...

```
<div><masked-input v-model="date" mask="11 / 11 / 1111" placeholder="Date"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can also occur when there is a component, *which exists*, imported and referenced in the components but not used in the template

```
...
</template>

<script>
import UnusedComponent from '@/Shared/UnusedComponent .vue'

export default {
  components: { 
      UnusedComponent ,
    },
```

removing the unused component import and reference will fix it